# ERROR MOSTRANDO DATOS MySQL (ONLINE) EN LISTVIEW

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, app

estoy llevando a cabo una aplicación para mostrar unos vinos, y tengo un error que tras investigar en numerosos sitios no consigo entender.
El caso es que sí me muestra los datos, pero con un "clic" de retraso. Es decir, la primera vez que clico, no me muestra nada, luego clico en otro sitio y me muestra la primera consulta; doy en otro sitio y me muestra la 2ª consulta... Y así sucesivamente. Me muestra los datos tarde, no sé si es porque tarda demasiado en conectar con la BD o qué, y la verdad es que me estoy agobiando un poco :(
Si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería mucho!!

Aquí está la clase ObjetoVino
        `public class ObjetoVino{
    private String proc_concreta;
    private String proc_general;
    private String familia;
    private String nombre;
    private String precio_copa;
    private String precio_botella;
    private String nota_cata;

```
public ObjetoVino(String proc_concreta, String proc_general, String tipo, String nombre, String precio_copa, String precio_botella, String nota_cata) {
    this.proc_concreta = proc_concreta;
    this.proc_general = proc_general;
    this.familia = tipo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.precio_copa = precio_copa;
    this.precio_botella = precio_botella;
    this.nota_cata = nota_cata;
}

public String getProc_concreta() {
    return proc_concreta;
}

public String getProc_general() {
    return proc_general;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return familia;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getPrecio_copa() {
    return precio_copa;
}

public String getPrecio_botella() {
    return precio_botella;
}

public String getNota_cata() {
    return nota_cata;
}

public void setProc_concreta(String proc_concreta) {
    this.proc_concreta = proc_concreta;
}

public void setProc_general(String proc_general) {
    this.proc_general = proc_general;
}

public void setFamilia(String familia) {
    this.familia = familia;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setPrecio_copa(String precio_copa) {
    this.precio_copa = precio_copa;
}

public void setPrecio_botella(String precio_botella) {
    this.precio_botella = precio_botella;
}

public void setNota_cata(String nota_cata) {
    this.nota_cata = nota_cata;
}
```

}`

Aquí el adapter del ListView:

```
public class AdapterVino extends BaseAdapter {

protected Context context;
protected List<ObjetoVino> items;

public AdapterVino(final Context context,final List<ObjetoVino> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

public void clear(){
    items.clear();
}

public void addAll(List<ObjetoVino> vinos){
    items.clear();
    for(int i=0 ; i < vinos.size() ; i++)
        items.add(vinos.get(i));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

public List<ObjetoVino> getItems() {
    return items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category,parent,false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.procedencia = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMostrarProcedencia);
        viewHolder.familia = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFamilia);
        viewHolder.nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMostrarNombre);
        viewHolder.precio_botella = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecioBotella);
        viewHolder.precio_copa = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecioCopa);
        viewHolder.nota_cata = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMostrarNotaCata);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ObjetoVino obj = items.get(position);

    if(items != null){
        viewHolder.nota_cata.setText(obj.getNota_cata());
        viewHolder.precio_copa.setText(obj.getPrecio_copa());
        viewHolder.precio_botella.setText(obj.getPrecio_botella());
        viewHolder.nombre.setText(obj.getNombre());
        viewHolder.familia.setText(obj.getTipo());
        viewHolder.procedencia.setText(obj.getProc_concreta()+"("+obj.getProc_general()+")");
    }

    return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView procedencia;
    TextView nombre;
    TextView familia;
    TextView precio_botella;
    TextView precio_copa;
    TextView nota_cata;
}
```

}

Y aquí la activity desde donde lo llamo (la idea es clicar en una zona, luego la familia del vino y ya se muestran aquellos que cumplen ambas propiedades):

```
public class MapaEspanaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button bAndalucia;
Button bMurcia;
Button bExtremadura;
Button bCastillaMancha;
Button bValencia;
Button bMadrid;
Button bCastillaLeon;
Button bAragon;
Button bCataluna;
Button bRioja;
Button bNavarra;
Button bPaisVasco;
Button bCantabria;
Button bAsturias;
Button bGalicia;


public ListView listaVinos;

//Lista que contendrá los vinos a mostrar
List<ObjetoVino> lista = new ArrayList<ObjetoVino>();
///////////////////////
AdapterVino adapter;

Button bTintos;
Button bRosados;
Button bGenerosos;
Button bEspumosos;
Button bBlancos;

//Variables para conectar con la base de datos

//IP de mi URL
String IP = "https://araiswine.000webhostapp.com" ;
//Ruta de las diferentes funciones en esta Activity
String GET_BY_ID = IP + "/obtener_vino_por_id.php" ;

ObtenerWebServiceGET hiloconexion;


String cadenallamada="";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa_espana);

    //Enlace con elementos visuales de XML

    bAndalucia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonAndalucia);
    bMurcia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonMurcia);
    bExtremadura = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonExtremadura);
    bCastillaMancha = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonCastillaMancha);
    bValencia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonValencia);
    bMadrid = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonMadrid);
    bCastillaLeon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonLeon);
    bAragon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonAragon);
    bCataluna = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonCataluna);
    bRioja = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonRioja);
    bNavarra = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonNavarra);
    bPaisVasco = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonVasco);
    bCantabria = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonCantabria);
    bAsturias = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonAsturias);
    bGalicia = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonGalicia);

    //Relaciono el ListView con el adapter
    listaVinos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaVinos);
    adapter = new AdapterVino(this,lista);
    listaVinos.setAdapter(adapter);



    bBlancos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonBlancos);
    bEspumosos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonEspumosos);
    bGenerosos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonGenerosos);
    bTintos = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonTintos);
    bRosados = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonRosados);

    //Listeners de los botones

    bAndalucia.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMurcia.setOnClickListener(this);
    bExtremadura.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCastillaMancha.setOnClickListener(this);
    bValencia.setOnClickListener(this);
    bMadrid.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCastillaLeon.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAragon.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCataluna.setOnClickListener(this);
    bRioja.setOnClickListener(this);
    bNavarra.setOnClickListener(this);
    bPaisVasco.setOnClickListener(this);
    bCantabria.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAsturias.setOnClickListener(this);
    bGalicia.setOnClickListener(this);

    bBlancos.setOnClickListener(this);
    bEspumosos.setOnClickListener(this);
    bGenerosos.setOnClickListener(this);
    bTintos.setOnClickListener(this);
    bRosados.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()){          //Si pulso en cada botón
        case R.id.botonAndalucia:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=ANDALUCIA";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case R.id.botonMurcia:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=MURCIA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonExtremadura:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=EXTREMADURA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonCastillaMancha:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=CASTILLA-LA%20MANCHA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonValencia:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=VALENCIA";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonMadrid:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=MADRID";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonLeon:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=CASTILLA%20Y%20LEON";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonAragon:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=ARAGON";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonCataluna:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=CATALUÑA";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonRioja:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=LA%20RIOJA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonNavarra:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=NAVARRA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonVasco:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=PAIS%20VASCO";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonCantabria:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=CANTABRIA";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonAsturias:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=ASTURIAS";


            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case R.id.botonGalicia:
            hiloconexion = new ObtenerWebServiceGET();
            cadenallamada = GET_BY_ID+"?PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL=GALICIA";

            //Muestro los botones y oculto la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

            //BOTONES FAMILIAS
        case R.id.botonBlancos:

            cadenallamada+="&FAMILIA=BLANCO";
            adapter.clear();

            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"1");



            //Oculto los botones y muestro la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Relacion con el Adapter
            reloadAllData();

            break;

        case R.id.botonRosados:

            cadenallamada+="&FAMILIA=ROSADO";
            adapter.clear();

            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"1");





            //Oculto los botones y muestro la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Relacion con el Adapter
            reloadAllData();

            break;

        case R.id.botonTintos:

            cadenallamada+="&FAMILIA=TINTO";
            adapter.clear();

            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"1");




            //Oculto los botones y muestro la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Relacion con el Adapter
            reloadAllData();

            break;

        case R.id.botonGenerosos:

            cadenallamada+="&FAMILIA=GENEROSO";
            adapter.clear();

            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"1");




            //Oculto los botones y muestro la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            break;

        case R.id.botonEspumosos:

            cadenallamada+="&FAMILIA=ESPUMOSO";
            adapter.clear();

            hiloconexion.execute(cadenallamada,"1");


            //Relacion con el Adapter
            reloadAllData();


            //Oculto los botones y muestro la lista
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //Relacion con el Adapter
            reloadAllData();

            break;

        default:                            //Si no pulso ningún botón
            listaVinos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            bBlancos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bEspumosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bGenerosos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bTintos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            bRosados.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            break;

    }
}

public class ObtenerWebServiceGET extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<ObjetoVino>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ObjetoVino> doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String cadena = strings[0];
        URL url = null; //URL de donde queremos obtener informacion
        ArrayList<ObjetoVino> listaAux = new ArrayList<ObjetoVino>();


        if(strings[1]=="1"){        //Obtener por Porcedencia General y Familia

            try {

                url = new URL(cadena);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); //Abrir la conexión
                connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" +
                        " (Linux; Android 1.5; es-ES) Ejemplo HTTP");
                //connection.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

                int respuesta = connection.getResponseCode();
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();



                if (respuesta == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){


                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());  // preparo la cadena de entrada

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  // la introduzco en un BufferedReader

                    // El siguiente proceso lo hago porque el JSONOBject necesita un String y tengo
                    // que tranformar el BufferedReader a String. Esto lo hago a traves de un
                    // StringBuilder.

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);        // Paso toda la entrada al StringBuilder
                    }

                    //Creamos un objeto JSONObject para poder acceder a los atributos (campos) del objeto.
                    JSONObject respuestaJSON = new JSONObject(result.toString());   //Creo un JSONObject a partir del StringBuilder pasado a cadena
                    //Accedemos al vector de resultados

                    String resultJSON = respuestaJSON.getString("estado");   // estado es el nombre del campo en el JSON

                    if (resultJSON=="1"){      // hay vinos que mostrar

                        JSONArray vinosJSON = respuestaJSON.getJSONArray("vino");
                        lista.clear();
                        listaAux.clear();

                        for(int i=0; i<vinosJSON.length();i++) {

                            ObjetoVino elemento = new ObjetoVino(vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("PROCEDENCIA_CONCRETA"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("PROCEDENCIA_GENERAL"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("FAMILIA"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOMBRE"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("PRECIO_COPA"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("PRECIO_BOTELLA"),
                                    vinosJSON.getJSONObject(i).getString("NOTA_CATA"));

                            listaAux.add(elemento);
                        }


                    }


                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return listaAux;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ObjetoVino> s) {

       lista = s;
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(ArrayList<ObjetoVino> s) {
        super.onCancelled(s);
    }
}

private void reloadAllData(){
    adapter.getItems().clear();
    adapter.addAll(lista);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Como sugerencia para ver si efectivamente es un tema de tiempo, ¿podrías generar algún método para que se bloquee tu pantalla, o aparezca algún indicio de que aún está cargando, para así identificar si se trata de un problema de tiempo?
La verdad es un poco raro todo el asunto, podría ser que se demora demasiado, lo ideal sería que puedas disparar algo que te indique que se está esperando una respuesta del servidor, así descartas eso.

Comment: No sé de qué forma hacer esa comprobacion...

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado una solución que consiste en poner el codigo de después de ejecutar el .execute("cadenallamada",1) en el onPostExecute(). De esta forma me aseguro de que no sigue en el hilo principal sin haber resuelto la consulta a la base de datos.